# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING don't know why

Tags: php

I was trying to make a form to insert data into a mysql database and I keep getting the same error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /home/u272231605/public_html/add_reg.php3 on line 20

Here's the code where the error is showed:

```
<html>
<body>

<?php
if (isset($_POST['Nombre Monstruo']) && !empty($_POST['Nombre Monstruo'])&&
    isset($_POST['Ataque']) && !empty($_POST['Ataque'])&&
    isset($_POST['Defensa']) && !empty($_POST['Defensa'])&&
    isset($_POST['Tipo']) && !empty($_POST['Tipo'])&&
    isset($_POST['Nivel']) && !empty($_POST['Nivel'])&&
    isset($_POST['Efecto']) && !empty($_POST['Efecto'])){
    $nombremonstruo = $_POST['Nombre Monstruo'];
    $ataque = $_POST['Ataque'];
    $defensa = $_POST['Defensa'];
    $tipo = $_POST['Tipo'];
    $nivel = $_POST['Nivel'];
    $efecto = $_POST['Efecto'];
    $db = u272231605_data;
    $host = mysql.hostinger.es;
    $user = u272231605_data;
    $password = 4Ym8ix2A;
    $con = mysql_connect($host,$user,$password)or die('No se ha podido conectar con      la base de datos');
    mysql_select_db($db,$con) or die('No se pudo conectar con la base de datos');
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO (Nombre del monstruo,Ataque,Defensa,Tipo,Nivel,Efecto" values('$nombremonstruo','$ataque','$defensa','$tipo','$nivel','$efecto')");
    echo "Guardado correctamente"
    echo "<a href=index.php"> Registrar otro monstruo </a>;
}
    else
    {
        echo "Han de introducirse todos los datos para que el registro de la   carta se complete.";
    } 

?>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance for the help provided :)

Comment: Might be an idea NOT to post your db details (including password) so publicly

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is here:

```
$db = u272231605_data;
```

and on other places. You should put double quotes around them:

```
$db = "u272231605_data";
```

Answer (score 0):

You've forgotten quotes in multiple places:

```
$db = u272231605_data;
$host = mysql.hostinger.es;
$user = u272231605_data;
$password = 4Ym8iJ2A;
```

Each of those values should be quoted. As they stand now, they're treated by PHP as undefined constants. But the last one (`4Ym8iJ2A`) is the cause of the error, because constants cannot start with numbers.

They should probably be:

```
$db = 'u272231605_data';
$host = 'mysql.hostinger.es';
$user = 'u272231605_data';
$password = '4Ym8iJ2A';
```

Answer (score 0):

As well as the missing quotes for variables, there are multiple issues with these 4 lines of codes. Please use a smart editor to highlight syntax and etc. Following lines are updated:

```
mysql_select_db($db,$con) or die('No se pudo conectar con la base de datos');
mysql_query("INSERT INTO (Nombre del monstruo,Ataque,Defensa,Tipo,Nivel,Efecto) values('$nombremonstruo','$ataque','$defensa','$tipo','$nivel','$efecto')");
echo "Guardado correctamente";
echo "<a href='index.php'> Registrar otro monstruo </a>";
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to wrap your variables in single quotes:

```
$db = 'u272231605_data';
$host = 'mysql.hostinger.es';
$user = 'u272231605_data';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$password = "4Ym8iJ2A";
```

The value needs single or double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a semi-colon on this line:

```
echo "Guardado correctamente"
```